# No php.ini What i must do?

Tags: php

Problem is bigger as no php.ini.

I want to connect mySQL with php vs code. I tryed use mysqli ext, but it is disabled:
[image]

Then i wanted to enable it in php.ini but i founded only php.ini-development and php.ini-production.
I checked directory of php.ini in php.info()
[image]
I looked for in google but couldnt fix it.

I enabled mysqli in php.ini-development and php.ini-production but it didnt workk.
So i dont know what is apache i use php server extension in vs code.
PHP version is 8

Comment: Copy the php.ini-development to just php.ini in the same directory…?

Comment: rename php.ini-development to php.ini on development machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Create a php.ini in the same director and copy all the information inside php.ini-development file and paste it into php.ini.

2- Search the lines below

extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll

3 - And remove de semicolon and save the file